# How to make viewDidLoad called more than once

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I know that `viewDidLoad` method may be called multiple times during `UIViewController`'s lifecycle. But how is that possible? How to make it called more than once not calling it directly? I tried doing it this way:

```
 UIView *view  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

self.view = view;
```

and whereas my view is actually changed, `viewDidLoad` is not called. Can anyone give an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first time you access a viewController's `view` property the view will be created with `loadView` and then you will receive the `viewDidLoad` call.

You will not receive the `viewDidLoad` call again unless the view is destroyed - this may occur if your viewController goes off screen and `UIKit` decides to purge any view's that are not visible. Thus next time you access the `view` property it will notice it does not exist and again create one with `loadView` and then call `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Note that as of iOS 6, a view will not be unloaded any more, therefore each instance of a view controller will only have loadView / viewDidLoad called once.

Comment: ...which, according to your comments on other answers, you already know. You should probably update the answer.

Comment: @jrturton I knew low memory didn't cause views to be purged anymore so I just wrote "[if]... `UIKit` decides to purge" - I don't know if there are any other cases where `UIKit` would decide to ditch views

Answer (score 0):

viewWillAppear method is an UIViewController method. Why you shouldn't call directly?

By the way there is no way to do that, while you assign an UIView to your self.view, id you are not doing it in the init or in the loadView or didLoad methods..

the life cycle is that:

- init
- loadView //change your view here
- viewDidLoad

Then you present the view and:

- viewWillAppear:
- viewDidAppear:

if you want to change the view during your uiviewcontroller life cycle you should do:

```
UIView *view  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[self viewWillAppear:NO]; //set to yes if you are making some kind of animation
self.view = view;
[self viewDidAppear:NO];
```

The will disappear and did disappear will be called according to the UIVIewController life cycle.

Comment: As per your edit to my answer (which others rejected) this no longer holds true for iOS 6 `On iOS 6, views are never purged and these methods are never called.`[UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: so you write non retro compatible code? Until iOS 5 is supported, my assertion remains true. You have to write code like viewDidLoad could be called again for a memory warning.

Comment: I never said to write non compatible code but instead opted to state if `UIKit` decides to purge views and not explicitly state when this might happen.

Comment: " this may occur if your viewController goes off screen and UIKit decides to purge any view's that are not visible" Those are your words. this is not the only eventuality. UIKit can destroy and re-create view for a memory warning too. Not in iOS 6, but if you write retro compatible code this is true!

Comment: `UIKit` will only purge a view if it is off screen, whether it's triggered from a low memory warning or some other metric (it's irrelevant) - the key point it that `UIKit` will only purge if your view is off screen and it decides it wants to for whatever reason